# MBA has occasional difficulty with campus WPA/WPA2 enterprise wifi network

Tags: macos, wifi, macbook-pro

I'm at the University of Texas, where we have a WPA/WPA2 enterprise wifi network. Much of the time it works great. Other times, it's tricky to connect *and stay connected*.

I can actually force it to connect long enough to load a webpage or two if I go into System Preferences > Network > Wi-Fi. In the bottom half of the window it's got `802.1X: Wi-Fi (restricted.utexas.edu)` next to a Connect button.

If I push connect, it says:

```
Authenticated via TTLS
Connect Time: 00:00:00
```

and then starts counting up. When it hits about 5 seconds, I find that I can load webpages. The Wi-Fi indicator, however, seems to think it's not connected (won't show the solid connection indicator, just the trying-to-connect animation), and after about 52 seconds, it seems to give up and decide it's time to try again -- which actually disconnects me.

Even after about two years of this I haven't found a consistent way of handling the problem other than rebooting the Macbook altogether. I find it'll connect eventually even if I don't. Turning Wi-Fi off and on may or may not help, but that may be my imagination.

I'd love to find a solution to this problem that doesn't involve rebooting, for obvious reasons. It's just not sustainable, because sometimes the computer will idle-to-suspend and then lose the connection again, which requires another reboot.

I'm using OS X version 10.8.4.

Comment: What OS X version are you running?

Comment: Oops, thanks. It's 10.8.4. I added it to the question.

Comment: Why would you loose the connection? is it a week signal ? or is there a limit imposed how long you can use it?

Comment: I have no idea why suspending would cause me to lose the connection. Doesn't the OS reinitialize network interfaces when it wakes up? I'd assume so. There's no time limit imposed.

Comment: Actually, in my experience, suspending my device requires me to re-establish my connection quite often. I don't think that's out of the ordinary, but I could be wrong.